# Apache poi with Spring AbstractXlsView style border work only for a number of rows

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I am currently working on a task where I have to export an xls report. Since the project I am working on it uses Spring, for the impl I have used the abstract Class called “AbstractXlsView” provided by Spring. Everything works fine, the files gets exported etc, up to the point of styling the xls file.

One of the requirements is to centre, add borders etc. The problem is that the style (i.e center text, border) is being applied to the xls table only up to "row 43". I used the debugger and the **createTableBorders** method is being called after row 43 up to the end of my list. But the style is not being applied after row 43 and I don't get it. See also the img attached. [image]

Anyone has any idea what is going on or what I am doing wrong?

```
Component
    public class ExportTemplateExcelView extends AbstractXlsView {
        @Override
        protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws Exception {

            List<SampleScenarioAndTask> scenarioAndTasks = (List<SampleScenarioAndTask>) model.get("templateToExport");
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(scenarioAndTasks.get(0).getScenarioName());
            sheet.setFitToPage(true);

            int rowCount = 0;
            Row header = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Some Header1");
            header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Some Header2");
            header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Some Header3");
            createTableBorders(workbook,header);

            Row templateRow = null;
            for (SampleScenarioAndTask next : scenarioAndTasks) {
                templateRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
                templateRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(next.getId());
                templateRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(next.getContent());
                templateRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(next.getType());
                createTableBorders(workbook,templateRow);
            }
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=template.xls");
        }

        public static void createTableBorders(Workbook wb, Row row){
            CellStyle style = getTableStyle(wb);
            for(int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++){//For each cell in the row
                row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(style);//Set the style
            }
        }

        public static CellStyle getTableStyle(Workbook wb){
            CellStyle style;
            style = wb.createCellStyle();
            style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            style.setWrapText(true);
            style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
            style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
            style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
            style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
            style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            //style.setDataFormat(doubleDataFormat);
            return style;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Re-use your cell styles! There is a hard limit on how many the file format supports

Comment: @ Gagravarr Sorry but what you mean by reusing ? I mean, I have only one method getTableStyle which return the style applied to the cells..

Comment: You seem to be creating a new cell style for each row. Don't! Create it once and re-use for every row